# Following tasks execution when top task changed

Tags: ansible

Want to execute the second task (task2) when the first task (task1) successfully added lines in the file (blockinfile).

```
 - name: nodes ip server configuration
   hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
   become: true
   become_user: root
   tasks:
     - include_tasks: step1_iptables.yaml
     - include_tasks: step2_script_firewall.yaml
```

======= more step1_iptables.yaml =========

```
- name: ip firewall configuration
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/init.d/test
    marker: "# {mark} Customer {{ admin_code }}-{{ ipadd }}-{{ ip }}-{{ rg1 }}-{{ rg2 }}"
    insertbefore: "## TO HERE"
    block: |
      $IPTABLES -A LOCALLY_MANAGED_RULES_INPUT -p udp -s {{ ipadd }} --sport 5060 -d $ip_SERVER_{{ ip }}_IP_ADDRESS --dport $ip_PORT -j ACCEPT
      $IPTABLES -A LOCALLY_MANAGED_RULES_OUTPUT -p udp -s $ip_SERVER_{{ ip }}_IP_ADDRESS --sport $ip_PORT -d {{ ipadd }} -j ACCEPT
    backup: yes
```

======= more step2_script_firewall.yaml =========

```
- name: Run script to save iptables
  command: sh /etc/init.d/firewall_node_local
  register: myoutput
- debug: var=myoutput.stdout_lines
```

=======================================================================

task2 only runs when lines in task1 added in file. if duplication then task2 related to script run skip.

```
   tasks:
      - include_tasks: step1_iptables.yaml
      - include_tasks: step2_script_firewall.yaml
        when: step1_iptables.yaml is changed
```

=======================================================================

Comment: You'll be better off with [iptables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iptables_module.html#iptables-modify-iptables-rules), or [ufw](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html#ufw-manage-firewall-with-ufw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) are for. Add *notify* to the 1st task

```
- name: ip firewall configuration
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/init.d/test
    ...
    backup: yes
  notify: script_firewall
```

and create *handlers* section with the handler

```
handlers:
- name: script_firewall
  command: sh /etc/init.d/firewall_node_local
```

Comment: One question, its not showing debug command output.                                                      register: myoutput
- debug: var=myoutput.stdout_lines

Comment: See [How do I write an Ansible handler with multiple tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618967/how-do-i-write-an-ansible-handler-with-multiple-tasks).